# When I set state via useState in parent component, my props in the child I'm passing down to are undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management, react-state

I have a parent component Listings, that has an array of objects from a seed file. I only want to load the first 9 of 14 objects on page load.

```
const Listings = () => {
  const [ listingsData, setListings] = useState(listings);

  const [ homesDisplayed , setDisplayNumber ] = useState(listingsData.slice(0, 9));
  const homes = homesDisplayed.map((home, index) => (
    <div className="col xl4" key={index}>
      <HomeListingCard 
        name={home.homeName}
        imageUrl={home.imageURL}
        beds={home.beds}
        baths={home.baths}
        isMultiSection={home.isMultiSection}
        sqft={home.sqft}
        startingPrice={home.startingPrice}
      />
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="listings-subheader">
          <h3 className="left available-homes">{`${listingsData.length} `}homes available</h3>
          <div className="right">
            <SortBy />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        {homes}
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <LoadListings listings={listingsData} homesDisplayed={homes} setDisplayNumber={setDisplayNumber} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Listings;
```

I use `const [ homesDisplayed , setDisplayNumber ] = useState(listingsData.slice(0, 9));` to set an array of 9 objects to state.

This works fine.

Then I am trying to pass my state down to a child component as props like this:

```
<LoadListings listings={listingsData} homesDisplayed={homes} setDisplayNumber={setDisplayNumber} />
```

When the page initially loads, those props have data. But when I click a button in the `<LoadListings />` child component to console.log(props), my data is all undefined.

`<LoadListings />` looks like:

```
const LoadListings = (props) => {
    const updateListings = (props) => {
        console.log(props.homes);
        // props.setDisplayNumber(...props.homesDisplayed, props.listings.slice(9, 12));
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={updateListings}>Load More</button>
    )
}
```

My goal is to click the button and have `updateLIstings` splice 3 more off the original array of 14 and add them to homesDisplayed array like so

```
const updateListings = (props) => {
        props.setDisplayNumber(...props.homesDisplayed, props.listings.slice(9, 12));
}
```

but props.homesDisplayed -- and all props -- are undefined.

Thank you.

Comment: From where you are passing listings in useState(listings) ?

Comment: in <LIstings /> i'm importing an array from a seed file. 'import listings from './seed.js';'

Comment: and when I look in react developer tools after I load the page, the props exist in my child component. but then i click the button with the function attached theres nothing there.

Comment: You are sending the event calling it `props` from the `onClick` callback. This event doesnt have a `homes` property so it returns undefined. I think you dont want to pass any argument: `const updateListings = () => {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you're not *actually* passing your props down to the `updateListings` function.

If you have a closer look at your function declaration, you'll notice that you've defined `props` as a parameter.  Then, on the `onClick` attribute, you're not actually passing anything *to* the function.

Think about the scope of the `updateListings` function...  You don't actually need to pass it anything, as it already has access to `props` from the parent scope.  Unfortunately, by defining `props` a second time as a function parameter, you're shadowing the higher-scope `props` (effectively telling the function to ignore it).

If you update `updateListings` to omit the `props` argument, it *should* work (barring any other problems in your code).

```
const updateListings = (props) => {
  console.log(props.homes);
  props.setDisplayNumber(...props.homesDisplayed, props.listings.slice(9, 12));
}
```

Side note: Instead of storing the sliced data in state, you may want to just store the number of items you intend to show.  That way, instead of reasoning about the data in state, you can simplify everything by just performing the slice in the render itself.  For example:

```
const [ listingsData, setListings] = useState(listings);

// Store number to display
const [ homesDisplayed , setDisplayNumber ] = useState(9);

// Slice before map, which'll update every time you increment `homesDisplayed
const homes = homesDisplayed.slice(0, homesDisplayed).map((home, index) => (
  <div className="col xl4" key={index}>
    <HomeListingCard 
      name={home.homeName}
      imageUrl={home.imageURL}
      beds={home.beds}
      baths={home.baths}
      isMultiSection={home.isMultiSection}
      sqft={home.sqft}
      startingPrice={home.startingPrice}
    />
  </div>
));
```

Another side note: typically you'll want to name your `[state, setState]` val/updater consistently following the convention of `varName, setVarName`.  That way it's less confusing to the reader (and you!) later on when you're trying to reconcile what controls what.

So I'd suggest changing `[homesDisplayed, setDisplayNumber]` to `[displayNumber, setDisplayNumber]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. And your suggestion about state only tracking the number and not the data helped a ton. I really appreciate it. You taught me a lot.